# Sybase's BCP utility for Redhat Linux

Tags: java, linux, sybase, bcp

I want to install Sybase's bcp utility in my linux box. 
I have a java application which internally use bcp to copy the data from text files to the database tables. I am not able to find any standalone installable for sybase's bcp.
Please suggest me what package needs to be installed for using sybase's bcp utility in Linux?

Regards,

Manoj

Comment: do you have the Sybase client installed?  it comes included, no need to install it separately.  it is in the `bin` directory, along with `isql`

Comment: I don't have sybase client installed in my linux machine. I installed sybase client in a windows machine to check for the bcp utility but I didn't get the bcp command after installation. Can you please tell me from I can download the appropriate client software for Linux which will provide me the bcp command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sybase client utilities are found on the Client CD.  Look for the [Sybase ASE Express Edition for Linux](http://response.sybase.com/forms/ASE_Linux_Download).  This should have the tools you are looking for.